# python function to remove vowels if a word has consonant

Tags: python, string

Rule 1: if a word has only vowels then retain the word as is
Rule 2: if a word has a consonant then retain only those consonants

But I was not able to my output according to above rules.

The output should be:

```
MSD sys i lv crckt nd tnns t
```

but my output is:

```
MSD sys lv crckt nd tnns t
```

Code:

```
def encrypt(message):
    word_list=message.split(" ")
    final_list=[]
    consonant_word=""
    vowel_list=("a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U")
    for word in word_list:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in vowel_list:
                    message=message.replace(letter,"")      
    return message

message="MSD says i love cricket and tennis too"            
print(encrypt(message))
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have edited the code.sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
def encrypt(message):
    vowel_set = set("aeiouAEIOU")  # set has better contains-check
    final_list = []
    for word in message.split(" "):
        if all(c in vowel_set for c in word):  # all vowel word
            final_list.append(word)  # unchanged
        else:
            # build word of only consonants
            final_list.append("".join(c for c in word if c not in vowel_set))
    return " ".join(final_list)

>>> encrypt('MESUD says i love cricket and tennis too')
'MSD sys i lv crckt nd tnns t'
```

Comment: No need to use the Split() 

     just use it like              for letter in message:

Comment: Thank u  @schwobaseggl  I am trying to solve this error for 2 days.Finally u solved in a second.Thanks once again

Comment: Yes I read it can you check my answer given below. is there anything wrong ? don't know am not an expert,new to python

Comment: @abhikrishnan But your answer does not do what the question asks for, which is that words containing only vowels should be left as is.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are replacing any vowel you encounter - so 'i' will be removed. You need to check if a word has any consonants before you remove vowels from it. You can do it like this:

```
def encrypt(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    vowels=("aeiouAEIOU")
    encrypted_words = []
    for word in words:
        if any(letter not in vowels for letter in word):
            word = ''.join([letter for letter in word if letter not in vowels])
        encrypted_words.append(word)
    return " ".join(encrypted_words)
```

The `if any(` line will be true if there are any non-vowels (i.e. consonants) in the word. Then this finds all the non-vowel letters:

```
[letter for letter in word if letter not in vowels]
```